# recv() does not get value from network

Tags: c, linux, sockets, tcp, network-programming

I Have a typical client server C socket program.

```
SERVER:
            if(ndp.cmd == 11)
            {   
                //ack1 = 0;
                puts("Query Command for Light 2");
                pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);  
                // ..Some critical stuff
                pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);    
                printf("ID: %d, Level: %d\n", new.address, new.level);
                ack1 = new.level; //This result is showing correct on server
                ack1 = htonl(ack1);
                send(client_sock, &ack1, sizeof(ack1), 0);              
            }

CLIENT:
    printf("Query Actual level Light2\n");
    dp.id = 2;dp.cmd = 11; dp.active = 0; dp.level = 0; dp.group = 0; 
    if( send(sock , &dp , sizeof(dp) , 0) < 0) { puts("Send failed"); }
    sleep(1);
    ret = recv(sock , &level1 , sizeof(level1) , 0);
    printf("Number of bytes received: %d\n", ret); //Always gives 4
    fflush(stdout);
    printf("Light level %x\n", ntohl(level1) ); //This prints 0 (incorrect)
    fflush(stdout);
    sleep(5);


    printf("Query Actual level Light2\n");
    dp.id = 2;dp.cmd = 11; dp.active = 0; dp.level = 0; dp.group = 0; 
    if( send(sock , &dp , sizeof(dp) , 0) < 0) { puts("Send failed"); }
    sleep(1);
    ret = recv(sock , &level2 , sizeof(level2) , 0);
    printf("Number of bytes received: %d\n", ret); // Always gives 4
    fflush(stdout);
    printf("Light level %x\n", ntohl(level2) ); //This prints correct value
    fflush(stdout);
    close(sock);

Expected output:
Light level 32 (hex value for 50);
Light level 32

Actual output:
Light level 0
Light level 32
```

So the problem is on same requests, 1st send from server is not received by client, but next recv() gives correct value.

Why is the data from 1st recv() getting lost, is it getting buffered and maybe I am getting the previous value in 2nd recv() ?

Please help.

Comment: You need to check what `recv` actually returns! What if the connection is closed? What if there's nothing to read currently (since you use the `MSG_DONTWAIT` flag)?

Comment: this check recv() < 4 means that I have not received an entire integer right? but this check always succeeds so i always get 4 bytes.

Comment: But if it fails you don't know *why* it failed. It could be so simple as the data haven't arrived yet so `recv` returns `-1` and set `errno` to `EWOULDBLOCK`, but it's not really an errors because of the `MSG_DONTWAIT` flag.

Comment: Also, please update your question with expected *and* actual output. And with the data you're sending

Comment: Your sending and receiving data methods seem open to possible failures. You should consider using select/poll mechanism for sequential read/write socket operations.

Comment: Are these sockets in blocking mode (the default)?

Comment: @BoraBozkurt I did the same using select(sock+1, &set, NULL,NULL,NULL); both places.

I get same result.

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29670567/411339

Comment: I'm having difficulty believing in the reality of this problem. If the reads always return 4, which itself is unlikely, you will receive whatever four bytes were sent. Are you sure you aren't sending the zero you're worried about?

Comment: No. The client is in a loop...so it sends out commands to server at intervals of 5 secs...and this happens during those 2 commands in the above code. Right now the only work around i could come up is to close the connection from client and re establish it each and every time i have to send a command to server.

Comment: Where is the evidence that the server isn't sending the zero?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your assumption is not wrong. It may be buffered. Also note that when the receiver reads data faster than the sender does send it, some `recv` calls may read no data since the sender did not send any data yet. That could be the cause of what you're describing.

**UPDATE**: If you plan to **always** send/receive the **same amount of data**, for example a 20-byte packet containing what you defined as a *command*, then you can wrap your `send` and `recv` in a loop. This loop will write (or read) a single command at a time. You **cannot assume** a call to `send` or `recv` will succeed, so you **MUST check for errors** as @Joachim mentioned in comments. Another thing to note is that `recv` MAY read less bytes than the specified, so you may have to read multiple times in order to receive the complete *command*. The same applies to `send`.

Comment: Did update to include some details about what you should consider. If you need to send/recv an arbitrary amount of data each time, then you need a way to identify the start/end of each _command_.

Answer (score 0):

You may use **select/poll** mechanism to check if there's new data has arrived to socket and waiting to be read properly. You can also check the amount of data has come to socket by invoking an `ioctl` call as the following:

```
{
       int size = 0;

       ioctl(socket, FIONREAD, &size);

       if(size > 0)
       {
             // do recv operation(s)
       }
}
```

Comment: I did the same using select(sock+1, &set, NULL,NULL,NULL); both places. I get same result.

Comment: You probably misused select function without setting the appropriate flags. Try using poll function, it is similar to select but much more convenient to use in some aspects. And please read and learn about this system call before using it properly and asking questions about it. http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html

Comment: The `ioctl()` is pointless here. It's an extra system call for nothing, when `recv()` already tells you how many bytes it received. And more bytes could arrive between the `ioctl()` and the `recv().`

Comment: You have made the same comment to my another answer, I replied you there too. Despite in this question the implementation is different, It is also not necessary to use recv call. It may be a socket read operation. The thing that I am pointing out is using polling mechanism (not using sleep between arbitrary socket operations) This method will be much more convenient. And if the socket is going to be read with read system call then using ioctl will be useful to check the amount of urgent data in the socket waiting to be retrieved.

Comment: It is necessary to use either `read()` or `recv()`. I didn't state otherwise. There is nothing in this question about urgent data. Your point escapes me.